# Are These Weaknesses Too Great For The Void?

Tags: magic

I came up with a class of mystical beings called Void. Void used to be human but were transformed into another species by the energies released by the Legendary Dark Dragon (Curse) when he died from a meteor. They look like people, sort of: they're mostly featureless (they have joints, fingers, arms, and so on, but lack the complete detail of a human being), have hands like talons, fangs instead of teeth, sunken voids for eyes (same shape, different look) and their lower half is replaced by a frill of shadows with ragged edges.

The Void are like ghosts in that normal objects and weaponry passes right through them. Even most energy weapons have no effect; the most extreme example of which would be that a nuke doesn't affect them. The reason is that they exist on *a different plane* as beings of darkness, making them affected by elemental light, dark, or *fire and electric attacks.*

My problem is that fire and electric attacks are rather common amongst mages in general (come on, how ubiquitous is the mage fireball or lightning bolt?) and I want the Void to be *almost* invulnerable, beings of incredible dark power like the Ringwraiths. However, light is inseparable from fire and electricity, the creation of either fire or electric energy results in the presence of the former as well.

So my question is, is a weakness to (elemental, must be magical in nature) fire and electric attacks too much of an advantage for the Void to be the bosses I want them to be?

Please Note: Voids are immune to nukes because they aren't the right *kind of energy,* they can only be harmed by energy that's on the right wavelength. In other words, since they are a manifestation of *elemental* or *magical* darkness, they can only be affected by magical attacks of the types listed as weaknesses above.

Also, for those who wonder how many mages exist in this world, they comprise about 25% of the population.

Comment: Question. An atom bomb creates a fireball of immense temperatures, flashes of light brighter than the Sun and an EMP. How are shadow creatures not affected if they're vulnerable to fire,light and electric? I think you mean they are immune to the physical devestation of a nuke, but don't want to assume.

Comment: Under the "Please Note" I edited in, I answered your question. It's not just that they're immune to the physical devastation of a nuke, they're immune to the light, heat, and electromagnetic pulse because it's not magical in nature and therefore doesn't even touch them. It's like a ghost-would a ghost be affected by a nuke?

Comment: that answers my question well. Thanks.

Comment: Glad it helped! I hope you answer my question.

Comment: So the ordinary mob with pitchforks and flaming torches won't touch them, it requires a mage? If so, how common are mages?

Comment: Mages would compose about 25% of the population.

Comment: I once read a book where the only thing that could kill main villain was a magical glass knife. Of which one only one existed. So a flame or electricy made of magic would be quite common in comparision.

Comment: Exactly, and my question is whether magical flame or electricity is too common to be a good weakness for what's intended to be a nigh-invincible boss species.

Comment: This is a story-based question (sorry). The limited weaknesses are only too great if your adversary's strengths and weaknesses are too unbalanced. Such a creature would be invulnerable to anything a modern-day soldier could do - but they might not be invulnerable to what a good scientist could do. In fact, once the "specific wavelength" of light is found, they're suddenly completely at the mercy of EM emissions. But, as I said, this all depends on whether or not your story is written to make them actually invulnerable by denying discovery of the weakness to the adversary.

Comment: Remember: when you ask about a rule, the rule exists independent of all stories. I.E., "Can my Void be invulnerable to all but one frequency of EM radiation?" Plausible answer: "Yes, but not just a single number. That's not how nature works. It would be more realistic to have a gaussian distribution centered on the target frequency." If you want to know if that's too strong an advantage, you must *also* describe the adversary so we can judge between the two rules - not the story.

Comment: You could make your creatures only vulnerable to mundane fire and lighting. This way, wizards blast it with their fireballs and lighting bolts, see that they're unaffected, and conclude that they're immune to all lighting and fire

Comment: @JBH -- I usually don't disagree on such matters, but I find myself in vehement disagreement with your premise. Often times I can see the argument from the other person's perspective, but in this case, I really can't see how this is a query of "actions of a character" or a matter of mere narrativity.  On the contrary, as I read it, this is a query of fundamental nature, and deep underlying substructures of a world. Don't let the mages and magic fireballs cloud your vision!

Comment: @elemtilas But how are we supposed to judge if the proposed creature design is "too powerful?" The only metric is one provided by the OP (and I dare someone to tell me we can judge this question by real life... grrrr....). As I said, a creature is only too powerful if its adversaries are too weak. That kind of comparison isn't worldbuilding, it's storybuilding. Think about it. "My creature can withstand nuclear blasts, is it too powerful?" answer: "only if its adversaries can't throw something more powerful than a nuke."

Comment: @JBH -- I think the answers given thus far (my own and AngelPray's) address this concern well, though coming from different perspectives. It's not a question of what can they throw that's "more powerful than a nuke", but rather, how can they access the wherewithal to *sufficiently counteract* the enemy. In other words, you don't necessarily have to utterly discombobulate an enemy's subatomic particles; you just have to apply sufficient pressure to his walnuts and he can be easily overcome.

Comment: @elemtilas The existing answers aren't answering the question (at least not any question I can find in the OP's post). At best, they're rationalizing why the question needn't be asked. They're little different than a [frame challenge](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7097/40609), and that's not a great example of how answerable a question is. So far I'm keeping my own counsel on this one.

Comment: @JBH -- No worries! I do see how the answers can be understood in terms of a frame challenge, and I for one am okay with that. They are valid answer types. It wasn't my intention to create one so much as to work with what the OP revealed in devising a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're thinking about this wrong. Voids aren't creatures of darkness, they're creatures of *darkness*. They're not weak to light, they're weak to *light*.

That sounds like nonsense, so let me explain. The word darkness has two (relevant) meanings:

- the physical absence of photons
- the antithesis of "life"/"good"/holiness/the universal creative essence

So naturally they aren't weak to fire or electricity, even fire/electricity of a magical nature. Flames can burn down cities, lightning can kill. But of course both can be used to create too; warm houses, power civilizations. Physically they are complex phenomena. Magically, they involve multiple layers of abstraction to generate. Thus unsuitable to oppose the (mostly) pure expressions of metaphysical darkness that are void entities.

Instead you need something deeper, simpler and closer to the creative source:

*the* Light.

I don't know much about your magical system. It could be a separate element: holy. It could just be a "powered up" version of normal magical electricity or magic.

Sacred flames instead of normal (even magical) fire.

Bolts of divine retribution instead of normal lightning.

---

Note that this doesn't actually require the participation of a god or even any "objective goodness" in your universe. I mean, from the voids perspective, mages who try killing them are evil. You just need to have a form of magical "light" (in the metaphysical sense) that is different from light in the mundane sense involving photons and such.

Comment: Coo, excellent answer that!

Comment: That's a good point....I could overcome the potentially devastating weakness of fire and electricity by having the Void's weakness be "divine" magic. Thank you, this is very helpful!

Answer (score 3):

**Dimensionality is Key**

These creatures are natural to and inhabit a different "plane", which we take to indicate a different area of dimensional space-time.

For example, the inhabitants of [**Flatland**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flatland) inhabit a two-dimensional area of space-time. These creatures  inhabit a Three-or-more-dimensional area of space-time. (Note that we're really only interested in the spatial dimensions here.)

When a 2D being meets a 3D being, he can not conceive the true nature of the 3D being, as he can only see the 2D "shadow" of the 3D reality. Should he meet a Cube, he can only examine and come to know it as a Square, because he can only conceive of the perimeter, the angles, the lengths of the line segments, but not the depth or height.

Should a 2D mage cast a fire circle (because in 2D space, they don't have balls) at a 3D Cube, the fire circle can only interact with an object or person of L x W (but not H, because in Flatland, height always equals zero) and thus *literally can not interact with the Cube at all*, because the Cube has a dimension of height and thus exists outside of the 2D mage's conceptual world. It may seem to her that the fire circle fully engulfs the Cube, and surely must destroy it!

But no! Once the energy is expended, the Cube remains unharmed, and indeed totally unaffected. We suppose one might posit that, technically, 0 mm of the Cube's outer skin is affected by the fire circle -- how much burn damage would that be for a 3D being?

And so it will be for these 3+ dimensional creatures. The fundamental issue here, as it is in Flatland, is that mages are applying the *wrong kind of energy*. Magic, as is well known, is an entity of the plane or world from which it springs. The 2D mage's magic fire circle is an entity of 2D space. An ordinary wizard’s 3D fireballs and electric attacks are entities of 3D space. Wrong kind of energy indeed! Their fireballs and lightning attacks will ultimately be of no use against a creature whose existent form is within more than three dimensions of space. It may be that a 3D attack can “push” one of these creatures out of 3D space, or far away within 3D space for a while, because the creatures shadow is cast within 3D space and thus, in some ways, may interact with it, but ultimately can have no lasting effect on the creature.

So, how can a 3D mage seriously attack a 3+D entity? She is going to have to figure out a way to manifest herself within 3+D space-time. A shadow of a 3+D being can be cast upon the 3D world (plane), just as the 3D being casts a shadow upon the 2D world of Flatland. Interaction of a kind can take place. A mage will have to work out how to access a kind of magic that will reverse the process. This is very advanced and esoteric dwimmery!

The mage who can successfully manifest herself within 3+D space-time can thus access & use such magical force as exists in that plane and bring it to bear on the creature, more or less on its own terms. But there is a price to be paid! Magic ... She’s already dabbling in the dangers of magical forces within a 3D world, and that's folly enough. She should be aware of the further dangers of extending her own 3D body into 3+D space: she might flip over, losing her grasp on 3D space entirely, thus becoming lost in 3+D space; she might become splunch, with half of her being wandering disconnected in each plane; she might end up losing control of a magic she has no native understanding of and wind up smeared across seventeen discontiguous dimensions of space-time. Very dangerous indeed!